# Ros_groovy_Workspace_Creation Catkin_Make Error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be an error when using catkin_make to create the ROS workspace using groovy distribution. When i type the catkin_make command to do environment setup in ~/catkin_ws/src, this is the error message i see.

```
CMake Error at /home/shaurya/ros_ws/devel/share/baxter_sim_kinematics/cmake/baxter_sim_kinematicsConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findbaxter_core_msgs.cmake or a configuration file
  for package baxter_core_msgs.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findbaxter_core_msgs.cmake or set
  baxter_core_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for baxter_core_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    baxter_core_msgsConfig.cmake
    baxter_core_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  baxter_simulator/baxter_sim_hardware/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193218/ros_groovy_workspace_creation-catkin_make-error/) by [GoBaxter](https://answers.ros.org/users/20265/gobaxter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your build is failing to find a dependency in either your system installation or your local workspace. The dependency in this case is baxter_core. You should ether install it to your system or add it to your workspace to compile.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0